# Desktop compatible Java Web Framework

Tags: java, model-view-controller, frameworks, zk

I need a Java Framework for Web development with these caractheristics:

Rich graphical UI; 
   Development tools available for most known IDE (Eclipse or Netbeans); 
   Free (preferencially non GPL); 
   Large community; 
   Easy to generate Web/Desktop/Mobile with the same code.

After some research we've found ZK Framework but we couldn't understand if we can compile for desktop or mobile.

Thnks

Comment: Web/Desktop/Mobile maybe it is worth to wait for JavaFX 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZK Mobile is a native client running on Java Mobile (or Android API). It does not require a modern browser, but, as I know, there is only a limited set of components (much less the number of Ajax components).

Answer (score 0):

I would be seriously surprised if a framework exist where the same GUI code can be used for web/desktop and mobile apps. The service -and model layer of your application should be reusable without any problem but you can't expect JSP's for isntance to be displayed in a swing or android application.

I didn't know ZK yet, looks nice but I guess there mobile part is intended for mobile webbrowsers and not mobile applications.

You could also consider [vaadin](http://vaadin.com/home), [GWT](http://code.google.com/intl/nl/webtoolkit/) or [apache wicket](http://wicket.apache.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to consider GWT seriously. Although it is not the best choice for mobile clients, gwt applications could be executed in your mobile device , if your mobile device's browser can execute javascript. But again I should express that native mobile applications would be better choice than browser based mobile applications.